# Remove string in file on linux

Tags: linux, mongodb, sed

I am looking to remove the `_id` field and its value which changes:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "54da1bee58743hd23947f493" }, "name":"david", "age":"33"}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5422222222222345d9f1f493" }, "name":"Dove", "age":"33"}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "54da1be57a4b727669f1f493" }, "name":"man", "age":"23"}


outcome:
{"name":"david","age":"33"}
{"name":"Dove", "age":"33"}
{"name":"man", "age":"23"}
```

I would like to use `sed` or any other command.

Comment: Use a projection document as the second parameter to the `find` method. Something like this : 

`db.collection.find({}, {_id: 0, name: 1, age: 1})`

Comment: need to use mongoexport which does not allow to remove the _id when creating json files. so unfortunately the only option seem to be removing the _id fields manually

Comment: Please update that requirement in your question.

Comment: that is why i did not refer to mongo in my request and only mentioned the need for commands in linux to substitute strings in file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy with [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

```
jq -c 'del(._id)' input.txt
```

O/P:

```
{"name":"david","age":"33"}
{"name":"Dove","age":"33"}
{"name":"man","age":"23"}
```